# List of ContentViews in a CarouselView with PullToRefresh

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have a list of two ContentViews that have the [PullToRefreshLayout plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout) within them surrounding ScrollViews. I'm not sure what's going on, but when you pull to refresh, the refresh circle appears but the Refresh Command never gets hit nor does the refresh circle ever finish.

Here is my CarouselView

```
<cv:CarouselView 
    Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ContentViews}" 
    Position="{Binding CarouselPosition}"
    x:Name="ContentCarousel">
    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <ContentView Content="{Binding Content}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
 </cv:CarouselView>
```

And here is an example of one of my ContentViews.

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <controls:PullToRefreshLayout 
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
        RefreshCommand="{Binding BindingContext.RefreshReceivingCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ReceivingContentView}}"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}" 
        RefreshColor="#4ABDAC">
        <ScrollView 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Style="{StaticResource cardScrollViewBackgroundColor}"> 
            <StackLayout 
                Padding="0,0,0,0" 
                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                x:Name="MainStackLayout">
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

I'm honestly not sure what's going on. I have tried different binding contexts on the refresh command but the command is never hit. Any ideas is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I sorta found a solution but not a huge fan.

I created an empty Constructor in my ViewModel that sets my Refreshing Commands. Then in the ContentView, I sent the BindingContext to the ViewModel. Seems redundant, but eh, works for now until I figure out the xaml binding.

Comment: Check your bindings, your problem is definitely there. What is `ReceivingContentView`? and how does it look the ViewModel you are using as BindingContext of your page?

Comment: The ReceivingContentView is the that current contentview. I'm not positive how the binding context is supposed to look. That was just a failed attempt.